# sef in joomla for dynamic urls

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-sef-urls, sef

I have made a joomla component and wise to make the site sef. The problem is that some of the URL from the components put values by get method. so that the next page can do the task accordingly. 
say

```
index.php?option=com_mediaonline&view=mediaonline&task=234&id=837
```

so that the next page will process the task accordingly, with task = 234 and id = 837. If i try to make it sef urls then nothing will work properly.

Is there any sef components or other extension available to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The best component for this is sh404sef, look for it in extensions.joomla.org and making the sef file for your component won't take more than 2 days

Comment: indded, sh404sef is amazing... this is the way to go!

Answer (score 2):

Have you not considered writing your own using a router.php file?

http://docs.joomla.org/Routing

Comment: Read the routing documentation so you understand how Joomla is getting the necessary parameters to build the page correctly. Once you understand that you can use the built in URLs or you can use a 3rd party extension and write your own plugin to integrate your component.

Answer (score 1):

Although sh404sef is useful I've found ACEsef to be better.

Comment: ACEsef is an SEF component righ?? I think it may be more useful for redirecting pages. can i use it with dynamic urls as i said above

Comment: Yes you just need to setup the correct parameters for the component